# What is the best way to minimize the RMSE?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using LinearRegression() from sklearn to predict. I have created different features for X and trying to understand how can i select the best features automatically? Let's say i have defined 50 different features for X and only one output for y. Is there a way to select the best performing features automatically instead of doing it manually?

Also I can get rmse using following command:

```
scores = np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(lm, X, y, cv=20, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')).mean()
```

From now on, how can i use this RMSE scores? I mean do i have to make multiple predictions? How am i going to use this rmse? There must be a way to predict() using some optimisations but couldn't findout.

Answer (score 1):

Actually sklearn doesn't seem to have a stepwise algorithm, which helps in understanding the importance of features. However, it does provide recursive feature elimination, which is a greedy feature elimination algorithm similar to sequential backward selection.

See the documentation here:

[Recursive Feature Elimination](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html)

Note that it is not necessary that it will reduce your RMSE. You might try different techniques like Ridge and Lasso Regression as well.

Answer (score 0):

RMSE measures the average magnitude of the prediction error.
[image: RMSE formula]

RMSE gives high weight to high errors, lower the values it's always better. RMSE can be improved only if you have a decent model. For feature selection, you can use PCA or stepwise regression or basic correlation technique. If you see a lot of multi-collinearity then go for Lasso or Ridge regression. Also, make sure you have a decent split of test and train data. If you have bad testing data you will get poor results. Also, check training data R-sq and testing data R-sq to make sure the model doesn't over-fit. 
It would be helpful if you add information on no. of observations in your test and train data and r-sq value. Hope this helps